CloudFormation error GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey
I have a problem with CloudFormation not finding the object in my S3 bucket. GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey The real problem is that I don't know what key it is trying to find. I am reading the deployment folder from Parameter Store and trying to join the path in my template as shown.
SubscriptionApiVersonedPath:
Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
Default: /
Description: The path of the versioned folder where the lambda zip files will be written


SubscriptionHealthCheckLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: subscription-health-check
    Code: 
      S3Bucket: "bwotn-deployment-pipeline"
      S3Key: !Join [ delimiter, [ !Ref SubscriptionApiVersonedPath, "/subscription-health-check.zip" ] ]
    Runtime: nodejs18.x
    Handler: index.handler

I believe the Template is reading the parameter value successfully, but I don't know how to be sure. I'm also not sure this !Join statement is correct.

It was a stupid mistake on my part. The word 'delimiter' does not belong in the !Join statement. That's supposed to be literally the delimiter. "/" for joining the strings

Also, presumably "/subscription-health-check.zip" should be "subscription-health-check.zip".
